# Where is django.contrib.auth.User defined in Django source code

Tags: django, authentication, django-authentication

In [Django official guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/auth/), it reads:

> Inside this `django.contrib.auth` model, there is a `User` class, who has following attributes (username, password, email, first_name, last_name).

When I check the source code in github, I did not find this definition in `django.contrib.auth`.
I can only see `class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):` in `django/contrib/auth/base_user.py` [on this link](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py), and `class User(AbstractUser):` in `django/contrib/auth/models.py` [in this webpage](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/auth/models.py).

Q1: what does `class models.User` mean in above official document, it means `User` is a class under `models.py` ?

Q2: if above is right, then where `User` class get attributes such as username, email etc?

Comment: I can not find the `inside this ...` part in the documentation you link to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Q1: what does class models.User mean in above official document, it means User is a class under models.py?

In Django one refers to a model with the `app_name.ModelName`. So if you specify a model, this is implemented in the `app_name/models.py`, but since models are defined in the `models.py` file, it makes no sense to include that in the name of the model.

For example the default for the [**`AUTH_USER_MODEL`** setting [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) is `auth.User`, since the name of the app is `auth`, and the name of the model is `User`.

> Q2: if above is right, then where User class get attributes such as username, email etc?

Through *inheritance*. Indeed if we look at the [source code of the `models.py` file [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.2.x/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L389-L397), we see:

> ```
> class User(AbstractUser):
>     """
>     Users within the Django authentication system are represented by this
>     model.
>     Username and password are required. Other fields are optional.
>     """
>     class Meta(AbstractUser.Meta):
>         swappable = 'AUTH_USER_MODEL'
> ```

and the [**`AbstractUser`** model [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/826a1659eed0b23f5b814d5a293eeaca20d29a6c/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L321-L386) defines the fields for `username`, `email`, etc.:

> ```
> class AbstractUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
>     # …
>
>     username = models.CharField(
>         _('username'),
>         max_length=150,
>         unique=True,
>         help_text=_('Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.'),
>         validators=[username_validator],
>         error_messages={
>             'unique': _("A user with that username already exists."),
>         },
>     )
>     first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=150, blank=True)
>     last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=150, blank=True)
>     email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), blank=True)
>     is_staff = models.BooleanField(
>         _('staff status'),
>         default=False,
>         help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.'),
>     )
>     is_active = models.BooleanField(
>         _('active'),
>         default=True,
>         help_text=_(
>             'Designates whether this user should be treated as active. '
>             'Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'
>         ),
>     )
>     date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)
>     
>     # …
> ```

`AbstractUser` is an *abstract* model. This means that Django does not create a table for it. Models that inherit from an abstract table will thus inherit fields, methods, etc. and these fields will then be defined on the model that inherits from `AbstractUser`.

Comment: Where the attributes `date_last_active` and `password` are defined? I did not see them in definition of `AbstractUser`.

Comment: @TianYan: `password` is defined in the `AbstractBaseUser`: https://github.com/django/django/blob/ca9872905559026af82000e46cde6f7dedc897b6/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py#L48 this is thus inherited by `AbstractUser`, and `AbstractUser` is inherited by the `User`, so it is "two level inheritance". The same with [`last_login`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/ca9872905559026af82000e46cde6f7dedc897b6/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py#L49).

Comment: ```class User(AbstractUser):
    UserID = models.CharField('userID：',help_text='Required', max_length=20, primary_key=True,unique=True, blank=False)```
NO `password` attribute defined here, as I thought it would have been defined somewhere in `django.contrib.auth`.  However, when I run the server, it pops up error  `You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'password' to user without a default`, then I add `password = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="")` to fix.

Comment: @TianYan: I think you better ask a new question where you include the relevant view(s), form(s) and model(s), since this comment is not very "accessible", since all items are written in the same paragraph.

Comment: sure, will do. coding 5 mins and troubleshoot 1 day. that is my life now.. :) I guess I still have a long way to go.